# Von Neumann stability vs eigenvalues of amplification matrix

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, stability

My, limited, understanding of the stability analysis of PDEs is that broadly speaking there are two methods: von Neumann analysis which looks at the growth the error of the solution, as described here

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_stability_analysis

and the method of constructing an amplification matrix and looking to see if the mag. of the largest eigenvalue is greater than or less than 1.

i.e. for a simple PDE (and using forward Euler for simplicity) $y' = \lambda \hat{\nabla} y \implies y^{n+1} = (1 + \Delta t \lambda \hat{\nabla})y^n $

where I chose a gradient operator instead of some other prefactor to emphasize i am going to do this with a particular finite difference discretization i.e. it's now a matrix equation with amplification matrix $G = 1+\Delta t \lambda \hat{\nabla}$. Depending on the discretization and value of $\Delta x$ in $\nabla$ we get some kind of CFL condition based on the eigenvalues of $G$.

Assuming the above is correct, i'm interesting in the following: the latter seems to be a statement about whether or not the solution is, at least locally, exponential (assume for now $\lambda$ is real). The former seems to be a statement about the behaviour of the *error* of the solution. In principle it seems one could have an accurate or inaccurate solution to an exponential. I also understand that in the von Neumann case an argument is made that if the PDE is linear then the equation for the error is the same as for the solution, and so if the error is unbounded then so will the solution (right?)

My question is then: to what extent is the above correct and in what sense are these two approaches equivalent?

Comment: My apologies, much of this is discussed here (i.e. circulant matrix requirement, which the central derivatives always are?)
https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2767/eigenvalue-analysis-vs-fourier-analysis-for-stability-and-their-equivalence
However my question regarding the modeling of the error vs the solution being exponential still stands, i think...

Comment: Also, what can one say here if $G$ is not circulant?

Answer (score 1):

This is a huge topic, and if you want to understand it you need to do a lot of reading.  It is also a very active area of research.  The techniques you've mentioned are the very basics.

To try to answer you briefly: von Neumann analysis is just the amplification matrix analysis applied to circulant matrices, since their eigenvectors are discrete Fourier modes.  And yes, for linear discretizations the truncation error and the solution obey the same equation.  There are some small problems in what you've written; for instance, stability (in the sense required for convergence) does not require that the amplification factor be less than or equal to unity -- it is more subtle than that.

Get a good introductory numerical analysis text, like LeVeque's "Finite Difference Methods for ODEs and PDEs".  You'll also want to learn about things like Lax-Richtmeyer stability and the Kreiss Matrix Theorem, for starters.